# Unable to run the Protractor tests in safari browser and build failed

Tags: selenium, javascript, protractor, end-to-end, safaridriver

My safari browser unable to locate the elements also and used so many delays:

[image: Screen Shot of log]

My Configurations are:

```
iMAC Version:       10.11.6 OS X El Capitan
Safari Version:     10.0.3
Protractor version: 5.1.1
Selenium Version    3.0.2
```

Also Attaching the screen shot of the log.